# How to query table1 first and make second query with results+table2 at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

```
SELECT LOGS.UserID, LOGS.UserName, LOGS.TransactionTime FROM LOGS
WHERE LOGS.TransactionTime BETWEEN DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',GETDATE()),'2001-01-01T06:00:00') AND DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',GETDATE()),'2001-01-01T08:00:00')
```

This is my first query. I get results of when workers start working from my LOGS table.

I have another table named Workers which includes all workers in it.

I want to compare `myfirstquery.UserID with Workers.UserID` and that query should show me who is not in **myfirstquery** (which means who is not working that day) but I need to do it in one query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   workers w
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   logs l
                   WHERE  w.UserId = l.UserId AND
                          l.TransactionTime BETWEEN 
                          DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '20010101', GETDATE()), '2001-01-01T06:00:00') AND 
                          DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '20010101', GETDATE()), '2001-01-01T08:00:00')
```

Comment: The same can be achieved using the `NOT IN` Operator too